# PostgreSQL 9.3 Query Design Optimisation - Improving speed

Tags: postgresql, optimization, postgresql-9.3

[image: ER Diagram]

I am looking to optimise a query that is currently taking ~2500ms to run in PostgreSQL 9.3. The reason I need to optimise it is that may have to be run frequently and it directly impacts user experience as it powers a set of visualisations in the UI.

There are three tables in use in the query (see diagram):

```
Simulation
- simulation_id serial (Primary Key),
- probability double precision,
- ... other columns ...

Result_Data
- result_data_id bigserial, -- primary key
- simulation_id integer foreign key references simulation(simulation_id),
- result_variable_id integer foreign key references result_variable(result_variable_id),
- time double precision,
- value double precision

Result_Variable
- result_variable_id serial, -- primary key
- ... other columns...
```

There are indexes on the primary keys, and an unique index on result_data(simulation_id, result_variable_id) as result_data_result_variable_id_simulation_id_idx.

The table sizes are as follows:

- Simulation: ~500 rows
- Result_Data: ~70,000,000 rows
- Result_Variable: ~544 rows.

The data stored in result_data is per simulation, for each result variable, store the time series data. There are ~240 time steps per variable.

The query currently being run is getting data across all simulations (with the simulation's given probability) for a given result_variable. The reason the query is run multiple times is that the user is given a chart per variable to navigate.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    s.probability, 
    r.time, 
    r.value 
FROM simulation s 
JOIN result_data r USING (simulation_id) 
WHERE
    s.run_id = 2197 AND 
    r.result_variable_id = 228433 
ORDER BY r.time
```

This query returns ~130,000 rows in ~2500ms.

The query analyze returns:

```
Sort  (cost=334630.68..334949.52 rows=127535 width=24)
  Sort Key: r.time
    ->  Hash Join  (cost=25007.56..323815.38 rows=127535 width=24)
          Hash Cond: (r.simulation_id = s.simulation_id)
          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on result_data r  (cost=2388.96..298167.82 rows=127535 width=20)
                Recheck Cond: (result_variable_id = 228433)
                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on result_data_result_variable_id_simulation_id_idx  (cost=0.00..2357.08 rows=127535 width=0)
                      Index Cond: (result_variable_id = 228433)
          ->  Hash  (cost=15161.60..15161.60 rows=596560 width=12)
                ->  Seq Scan on simulation s  (cost=0.00..15161.60 rows=596560 width=12)
```

Any help in optimising this further would be most appreciated. I've simplified everything as much as possible, the server itself is tuned for the PostgreSQL 9.3 installation.

EDIT to include EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, BUFFERS)

```
Sort  (cost=113825.62..113825.77 rows=60 width=24) (actual time=308.862..338.584 rows=128821 loops=1)
  Sort Key: r.time
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 13137kB
  Buffers: shared hit=131844
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..113823.85 rows=60 width=24) (actual time=0.070..242.060 rows=128821 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=131844
        ->  Index Scan using simulation_run_id_idx on simulation s  (cost=0.42..22.62 rows=280 width=12) (actual time=0.043..0.835 rows=539 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (run_id = 2197)
              Buffers: shared hit=514
        ->  Index Scan using result_data_result_variable_id_simulation_id_idx on result_data r  (cost=0.57..404.06 rows=237 width=20) (actual time=0.015..0.350 rows=239 loops=539)
              Index Cond: ((simulation_id = s.simulation_id) AND (result_variable_id = 228433))
              Buffers: shared hit=131330
Total runtime: 356.395 ms
```

There are slight changes as I have added an index to Simulation(simulation_id) - the query still runs at ~2500ms.

Comment: What are you doing with so many rows?  Isn't a chart with so many data points a bit congested?  Also, the actual execution time is 356 ms.  Could you show a query which is slow?

Comment: "*Total runtime: 356.395 ms*" this if a **lot** faster then the 2500ms you claim. What you probably see is the runtime of the query **plus** the time it takes for your SQL client or application to receive, process and display 128821 rows

Comment: @dezso this data is used to create a chart - it's processed down using a probability density, resulting in 3 time series lines with ~270 time series point each.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are indeed correct. Runs at ~600ms when directly on the server.

~600ms is still pretty slow considering the number I need to run though. Is there anyway you guys can see to improve it? I appreciate the current major overhead is the data transfer time, but I can work on that separately.